# Project unable to search MinGW after updating tool chain from Cross GCC to MinGW

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I initially created a C++ Project in Eclipse CDT using Cross GCC compiler. But I did not have Cross GCC on my PC. So the Project was giving error:

```
Program "g++" not found
```

So later I changed toolchain from Cross GCC to MinGW in `MyProject->Properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor`.

The PATH in `MyProject->Properties->C/C++ Build->Environment` got updated to `${MINGW_HOME};`...
I have not installed MinGW in C:\MinGW, that is why specified MINGW_HOME environment variable.

NOTE: If I create Project using MinGW, the Project gets MinGW location. So MinGW installation is proper.

So what are all the things I have to change when changing Project toolchain from CrossGCC to MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

Go in MyProject->Properties->C/C++ General-> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
Click Restore Defaults.
Even after changing toolchain from Cross GCC to MinGW, Project Includes are not added to Project.
After clicking Restore Defaults and applying, MinGW includes are added to Project.